# Cannot open file in terminal using visual code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

This is the error I received:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PHPUnit\Runner\Exception: Class 'tests/FirstTest' could not be found in '/Users/dwayneclarkjr/Documents/Testing/tests/FirstTest.php'. in /Users/dwayneclarkjr/Documents/Testing/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:99
>   Stack trace:

I'm running visual code and learning how to test code. The Terminal is built inside it, so when I run this code to test first assertion function;

first command I used:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit test/FirstTest.php
```

and got this error:

> no such file or directory

That's the error I got in the terminal.

Comment: Try going into you test folder and running `phpunit ./FirstTest.php`

Comment: error recieved bash: phpunit command not found

Comment: Your first code block says “test” where your other code blocks says “tests”. Are you sure you’ve typed everything correctly? In your terminal, run `cwd` to print out the current working directory — you might not be in the folder that you think you’re in.

Comment: cwd command is not found it says. and  to let you know i am new at this. and yes i typed everything correctly, im following a course from treehouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are at '/Users/dwayneclarkjr/Documents/Testing/tests/FirstTest.php', in your terminal, try running

```
cd ../..
```

This should put you at the root of /Users/dwayneclarkjr/Documents/Testing

From there run your command:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit test/FirstTest.php
```

If you aren't a the above location it will probably still error. Can you provide the location you're at by running

```console
cd
```

or

```
cd ,
```

Comment: im at the root after running that command ->  Dwaynes-MBP:~ dwayneclarkjr$